# Can't convert string object to time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe containing different recorded times as string objects, such as `1:02:45`, `51:11`, `54:24`.

I can't convert to time objects, this is the error I am getting:

> "time data '49:49' does not match format '%H:%M:%S"

This is the code I am using:

```
df_plot2 = df[['year', 'gun_time', 'chip_time']]
df_plot2['gun_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_plot2['gun_time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
df_plot2['chip_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_plot2['chip_time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Because `49:49` doesn't have the hour part? Looks like the proper format should be '`%M:%S'` for this?

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you add some sample data? The issue seems to come from the fact your data is not alsways formated the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a common format in the time Series by checking string len and adding the hours as zero `'00:'` where there are only minutes and seconds. Then parse to datetime. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["1:02:45", "51:11", "54:24"])

m = s.str.len() <= 5
s.loc[m] = '00:' + s.loc[m]

dts = pd.to_datetime(s)
```

```
print(dts)
0   2021-12-01 01:02:45
1   2021-12-01 00:51:11
2   2021-12-01 00:54:24
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be because for %H python expects to see 01, 02, 03 etc instead of 1, 2, 3. To use your specific example 1:02:45 may have to be in the 01:02:45 format for python to be able to convert it to a datetime variable with %H:%M:$S.